# Getting an error 'Error: INSERT INTO `call`.`logs` (id, hashkey, ) VALUES (, XXX, )'

Tags: php, mysql

I have been retrieving call logs from a cdr and dumping them into a database in MySQL. Of late the database crashes and the was giving me duplicates and junk characters so i modified to the below code.
  **modified code**

```
 $file1 = file_get_contents('file:///C:/Users/thy/Desktop/2011_0419_1531_v3.12R/cdr/'.$newname, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);

$arr1 = explode("\n", $file1);
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
    $colArray = [];
    $colArray['id'] = null;
    $colArray['hashkey'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));

    $split = explode(";", $value);
    foreach ($split as $key => $val) {
        # code...
        $arr   = (explode('=', $val));
        $field = 'ch';
        $item  = '0';
        $field = $arr[0];
        $item  = $arr[1];
        $item  = str_replace(str_split(')(\/'), '', $item);

        $colArray[$field] = $item;
    }

    $columns = implode(', ', array_keys($colArray));
    $values = implode(', ', $colArray);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `call`.`logs` (" . $columns . ") VALUES (" . $values . ")";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}
```

the above code keeps giving me errors

> Error: INSERT INTO `call`.`logs` (id, hashkey, ) VALUES (,
>   797d8782a433b30e196fafc0ce01d09b, )
> You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near ') VALUES (,
>   797d8782a433b30e196fafc0ce01d09b, )' at line 1

**Original code is below (the one i modified it from)**

$file1 = file_get_contents('file:///C:/Users/thy/Desktop/2011_0419_1531_v3.12R/cdr/'.$newname, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
    $arr1 = explode("\n", $file1);

```
$data1 = array();


foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
$split = explode(";", $value);

$keys = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
//insert key to identify call. 
$sql = "INSERT INTO `call`.`logs` (`id`, `hashkey`) VALUES (NULL, '{$keys}')";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

foreach ($split as $key => $val) {
    # code...
    $arr=(explode('=', $val));
    $field='ch';
    $item='0';
    $field=$arr[0];
    $item=$arr[1];

    echo $field . " --";
    echo "<br/>";
    echo $item;
//sql 

$sql = "UPDATE logs SET {$field}='{$item}' WHERE hashkey='{$keys}'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

    echo "done";

//$conn->close();

}   echo "<br/>";
}
?>

<?php
```

Comment: What is the structural definition of the DB table logs?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: @xbile. My answer fix your problem? Please, let me know for trying to help you in other way if not...

Comment: +gileadkenzo it didnt

Comment: Are you getting the same error? Which one are you getting for now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the generated/devised INSERt statement

> INSERT INTO `call`.`logs` (" . $columns . ") VALUES (" . $values . ")";

There is an extra comma getting appended without column name?

Comment: No It's wrong, you just surround them all with one "

Comment: @wajeeh See the error message and it would clarify why the syntax issue pops up because of the comma(,) attached after hashkey column name but no further columns mentioned Error: INSERT INTO call.logs (id, hashkey, )

Answer (score 0):

If **id** is an autoincremental field. Try this:

```
INSERT INTO call.logs (id, hashkey) VALUES (default, '797d8782a433b30e196fafc0ce01d09b')
```

Comment: If it's auto incremental you can drop the id. `INSERT INTO call.logs (hashkey) VALUES ('{$keys}')`

Comment: Indeed. You can use NULL value as well. Thanks @ChrisMagnussen